# Compass / Sass automatic generate IE css files

Tags: compass-sass, sass

Is there a way to automatic generate an IE specific file like in the example below?

```
   /* content.scss */
.box {
    color:red;
    .ie7 & {
        color:green;
    }
}
```

This generates two files :

```
/* content.css */
.box {
  color: red;
}


/* ie7.css */
.ie7 .box {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to setup 2 different Sass files, but you could do it with a custom mixin:

http://jakearchibald.github.com/sass-ie/

```
$old-ie: false !default;

@mixin old-ie {
    // Only use this content if we're dealing with old IE
    @if $old-ie {
        @content;
    }
}

.test {

    float: left;
    width: 70%;

    @include old-ie {
        // These hacks won't appear in the normal stylesheet
        display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        whatever-ie-needs: le-sigh;
    }
}
```

Comment: the non-ie specific css will be output in the ie-specific file, though :/

Comment: So you make a second mixin that's the opposite and hides CSS that IE can't/shouldn't use.

Comment: scss is supposed to make css readable. let's just follow https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/241

Comment: And?  Sass already has the tools to do what you want (@if/@content directives), as nex3 repeats over and over in that discussion.  Blocking your styles with not-for-ie/ie-only mixins isn't any more or less readable than anything suggested in the thread.